# Account Private Keys not Logging with Web3.js with Pure Javascript and HTML on browser

Tags: web3js, tokens, erc-20, ethereumjs

Here is the code below, I want to create accounts using web3 js and logged the private keys. But am having an error Reference Error and keys not logging. I followed the docs at https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.6/web3-eth-accounts.html# , I want to do it from client side, no node JS needed

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="web3.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>


<script>


var Accounts = require('web3-eth-accounts');

// Passing in the eth or web3 package is necessary to allow retrieving chainId, gasPrice and nonce automatically
// for accounts.signTransaction().
var accounts = new Accounts('ws://localhost:8546');

console.log(web3.eth.accounts.create());


    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are u using ganache at Port 8546?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check [this](http://browserify.org/) tool. You need to make your javascript browser compatible to use `require()` features.